# Run an AppleScript .app from Excel 2016 button on Mac

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have an AppleScript .app file that opens a Word document. I have created a button in Excel 2016 that assigns a file name to a variable. I would like to be able to pass this filename to an AppleScript .app and run the .app by clicking the button.

**Is this possible? If so, how?**

```
Sub buttontest2()
Dim objdoc As Object

FileName = "/Volumes/256SSD/word docs/shortcut keys.docx"
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    launch
    open file fileName
end tell
End Sub
I do not know how to incorporate the tell loop into VBA. There is probably a better method for doing this bit I am not aware of it as I am just starting with Applescript
```

Comment: So you want a button in excel to activate a script that gets the name of the current document and sets it to a variable?

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you could post the AppleScript app code so we can better visualize what it is you're trying to ask us.